# Ca I write planningless?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

As pointless, meaningless, can I write: **planningless** in a scientific paper?

Comment: Can you write it? Yes. Will it be understood? Probably. Have others used it previously? Yes, but not often. Is it in the dictionary? No.

Comment: "Unplanned" is much more common.

Comment: Use a thesaurus to find words with close meanings.

Comment: thank you @ThePhoton